# Possible to format Excel databar to have autocontrasting color?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have conditional formatting on a cell using a data bar. I would like to have the value show in the cell but in a contrasting color. For example if the cell is at 50% and is therefore half black and half white, I would like the 5 and half of the 0 to be in white (against the black) and the other half of the 0 and the % sign to be in black (against the white). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

[image: SO51957486 example]

and the answer is No. (I fudged it by overlaying an image.)